# Rebinding a listview on back pressed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an activity that has a listview in it, it gets binded onCreate with data, the problem i am having is that when i click on one of the items in the listview it sends me to another activity and then if I pressed back the listview is being cleared.. Which event or handler do I need to call to rebind the listview in the activity that has the listview? (the back is the phone back "arrow").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill the listview with data in onResume instead and you should be good to go. onResume will get called when the user goes back to your activity via the back arrow.